# In MongoDB, how do I increase how much rows of information can be printed on the shell?

Tags: mongodb

For an assignment, I've performed a Map-Reduce job on a db with 1 milion documents, set the output to inline, and stored the output in a variable:

```
var maxPrices = db.prices.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out: {inline: 1}});
```

The results array inside the variable contains 1061 reduced results.

If I try to print the variable's content, by writing in the mongo shell:

```
maxPrices.results
```

And I try to scroll up to the first results, I can't.
The max amount of information that the shell retains as viewable is approximately the last 600 results in the array.

I know I could save the output in a collection to see all of it, but I need to specifically do this with a variable.

I've tried looking for stuff like "mongodb increase shell size", but the only thing I've found is how to increase the batch size when using find()

Comment: That's not the "shell" but a constraint on your terminal window. 1000 results is a lot, so it would probably be more practical to output to a collection or limit your input until you get down to a more workable result size. But if you must, then look at increasing your terminal buffer. Likely already existing answers on [superuser.com](http://superuser.com) or other sources. But not a shell configuration issue.

Answer (score -1):

Solved: I needed to increase the shell buffer ("buffer" was the word to look for, it didn't occur to me).
On Ubuntu 16.04, you can do it by:
- opening a shell
- clicking on: Modify > Profile Preferences > Scrolling
- either disabling the limit on scrolling, or setting it to a higher number

(I've translated the menu path from Italian, the actual menu path might be different in English)